# Issues with python 3.x multiline regex?

Tags: python, regex, xml

I am very new to python and started coding with it a few weeks ago. Since now I was able to resolv any issues with researching and reading. But this issue gives me now headaches since several hours and I can't seam to find the correct solution.

I created a sample xml ([test_file.xml](https://seafile.load-it.com/f/fba09cbd521d4dbb9a67/?dl=1)) on my hard drive in the folder where also my read_xml.py file is located.

Content of `read_xml.py` (before)

```
import re

with open('test_file.xml') as xml_source:
  data = xml_source.read()
  xml_result = re.compile(r'<title>(.+?)</title>')
  mo = xml_result.search(data)
  print(mo.group(1))
```

gives me back `TinkerTry` which it should.

But if I go further like this

Content of `read_xml.py` (now):

```
import re

with open('test_file.xml') as xml_source:
  data = xml_source.read()
  xml_result = re.compile(r'<title>(.+?)</title>\n<link href="(.+?)"/>', re.MULTILINE)
  mo = xml_result.search(data)
  print(mo.group(1))
```

it does not seam to find / match anything anymore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: don't. If you're in the state of learning `Python` (or any other language, for that matter), trying to analyze `XML` nodes with regular expression is usually considered [**an anti-pattern**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Instead, use a parser (that's what they were made for).

---

For your specific example this might come down to:

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for title in root.xpath("//item/title"):
    print(title.text)
```

And yields

```
It's Bugtober, with Adobe Flash crashes, numerous CVE vulnerability patches for Wi-Fi and routers, and an Intel SPI vulnerability patch for most Xeon D Supermicro SuperServers
Supermicro Xeon D SuperServer BIOS 1.2c / IPMI 3.58 released
Windows 10 Fall Creators Update introduces GPU monitoring features built right into Task Manager
VMUG Advantage EVALExperience includes latest VMware vRealize Log Insight 4.5 syslog server appliance for easy vSphere, vSAN, IoT, and networking gear log file analysis
Road-warrior productivity boosted by ASUS ZenScreen MB16AC secondary travel display that connects to Mac or PC with just one USB-C or USB 3.0 cable
```

---

You see, this makes for cleaner and better to understand code. You might need to install **[`lxml`](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#the-xpath-method)** via `pip install lxml` first.

---

Note: *there was an error in your XML file which I needed to correct for this to work (the `link` tag was opened but never closed)*.

Comment: thanks for the quick replay, whats the advantage from lxml over the built-in xml.etree.ElementTree?

Comment: It has better error reporting functions and supports `HTML`.